# mysql_fetch_array and while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from DB and print it on the page. I use next select:

```
$tableIndex=mysql_query('SELECT table_index FROM table_names');
```

When I use a `while` loop to print, it's ok.
Code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex) ){
        echo $row[0].'<br>';}
```

Result:

```
1st

2nd

3rd
```

But without `while` loop, it gives me just first element of array.

**Code:**

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex);
    echo $row[0].'<br>';
    echo $row[1].'<br>';
    echo $row[2].'<br>';
```

Result:

```
1st

_

_
```

(where "_" is blank space)

Can someone expalin why it works so strangely?

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Comment: strange??? do you know what loop is for?

Comment: I already read php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php, but there are no word why mysql_fetch_array cannot be used whisout "while" loop

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're fundamentally misunderstanding how these things work.

The "array" in `mysql_fetch_array` is not an array of all the records, but an array of the data within the current record.

In your case, you're only fetching a single field, so the array will only contain a single element (ie `$row[0]`), but the principle is the same -- it's an array of the single record that you have just read.

Only the data for the current record is in the array at any one time. That's what the `while` loop is for; it goes back any loads each record one after the other.

If you want to create an array that contains all the data, you need to do it like this:

```
$fullData = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex) ){
    $fullData[] = $row[0];
}
```

That will put all the data that you're reading into a single big array, which is what you're expecting. Now you can do what you wanted to do in the question:

```
echo $fullData[0].'<br>';
echo $fullData[1].'<br>';
echo $fullData[2].'<br>';
```

Hope that helps.

It's worth pointing out here that the `mysql_xxx()` family of functions are deprected and considered obsolete. If you're just learning PHP (which would seem to be the case), I strongly recommend that you stop learning these functions, and learn the `PDO` library instead. It is more modern and has a lot of features that the `mysql` functions can't provide. In addition, future versions of PHP will remove the `mysql` functions entirely, so you'll have to switch at some point -- it may as well be now, while you're still learning.

Also (to keep things relevant to the question), the PDO library has a feature that does in fact do what you're looking for in a single function: `PDO::fetchAll()`. Using this method means that you **can** fetch all the data into a single big array in one line with no need to do a while loop. The code would look a bit like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

(example taken from the PHP manual for [`PDO::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php))

Comment: @Braggae - I've also added an additional bit to the answer that gives you a further possible solution using a more modern API.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I realy just start learning PHP, and it's very good point to swich to another library.

Answer (score 2):

Every time your loop loops around, this code is executed again:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex);
```

So every time $row gets the new value. The equivalent without a loop would be:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex);
echo $row[0].'<br>';
$row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex);
echo $row[0].'<br>';
$row = mysql_fetch_array($tableIndex);
echo $row[0].'<br>';
```