# How to turn mysql array to php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
        $cg= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$postid' 
        and  status='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
       while($sd= $cg->fetch_assoc()){
       $title= $sd['title'];

        }
```

**What i want to do is turn var $title to something like**

```
     $mytitle[1] = 'first title';

     $mytitle[2] = 'second title';

     $mytitle[3] = 'third title';
      $randnews= rand(1, 3);
      echo $mytitle[$randnews];
```

Comment: `$title[]= $sd['title'];`

Comment: Sorry i am php newbie. Thanks Steve

Comment: directly write  $cg->fetch_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,I have tried based on my database table query,
It's working as you expected.

**Code:-**

```
<?php
     require_once("connect.php");
     $sql=("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$postid' and status='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
     $result = $con->query($sql); 
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      $array[] = $row['title'];      
      }
     echo "After Sorting".'<pre>';
     print_r($array);
     echo '</pre>';     
?>
```

**$con** is variable of connection class.

> $con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$my_db);

**Output:-**

> ```
> [xyz] => "test"
> [abc] => "tester"
> [pqr] => "user"
> [res] => "test"
> ```

Hope this helps

Comment: As I already commented in Sarath's answer, there is no need to traverse the query result and build an aux array since you can get it by using `fetch_all()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

```
$cg = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$postid' and  status='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
$mytitle = $cg->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$randnews = rand(1, 3);
echo $mytitle[$randnews]['title'];
```

Comment: `SELECT title FROM..` if only the title is required. Also `rand(1,3)` ignores the 1st result and the 5th,6th etc. It also breaks on less than 4 results. As the order is already randomized in the SQL, simply echo the 1st result

Answer (score 0):

```
$cg= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$postid' and  status='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
       while($sd= $cg->fetch_assoc()){
       $title[]= $sd['title'];
        }

print_r($title);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 $cg= $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$postid' and  status='1' ORDER BY RAND()");
           while($sd= $cg->fetch_assoc()){
           $title[]= $sd['title'];
            }
    echo $title[1]['col1'];
    echo $title[3]['col2'];
```

and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17023239/3164682) is the complete reference..

Comment: There is no need to traverse the query result and store each row/field since you can use `fetch_all()` directly

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = array();
while($sd= $cg->fetch_assoc()){
   $title[] = $sd['title'];
}
your can user print_r($title) to check how the array looks 
it will look like 
Array(
  0 =>'first title',
  1 =>'second title',
  2 =>'third title'
)
```

A PHP array always start with 0 as a key and not 1. 
So if array length is 3 , the keys are 0 1 2 and so use `rand(0,2)` 
ie. `rand(0,count($tile)-1)`